# How to remove background colors in antialiasing pixels in Eevee?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I have a shadeless red material applied to the default cube.  The world background is green.  When the scene is rendered with Eevee, transparent green pixels appear at anti-aliasing pixels along the contours of the cube.  How I can remove the green color and make the anti-aliasing pixels purely red?  The green color seem to come from the world background.  No transparent green pixels if the same scene is rendered with Cycles.

[image]

Comment: Eevee questions are not on topic as 2.80 is not an official version.

Comment: have you tried increasing the samples?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried increasing the number of samples.  It only affects the way how anti-aliasing patterns are generated, and the green background color is visible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Change the world background to a black color and it should look fine.

In this example I am using a world enviroment but wanted a color/alpha to appear for the camera/render.

At first the render came out with a light blue border over objects, and as I changed the "world bg" to black with the light path node, the render came out fine, without borders.

I hope this can be understood easily, im at work and typing this without thinking it too much

[image]